# How to wait for browser.driver.findElement to return

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, webdriver, protractor

I am currently testing all elements on my website. The typical flow is:

1. Load webpage
2. Find element
3. Click element

My setup uses switch statements to pick the correct `browser.driver.findElement` to find the desired element.

Example code:

```
  switch (element_name) {

  case "red button":
  return browser.driver.findElement(By.id('redButton'));
  break;
```

This return value is then used with `click()` to click on the element.....

**My issue is that it seems that the elements can't consistently be found after the web page loads.** I will inconsistently get errors that reference unable to find element or element is not visible. So I am looking for a way to keep checking if the element is loaded, then attempt to click it. I have seen the examples using `EC.visibilityOf()`, but it looks like I can't use `browser.driver.findElement` with that.

I have done a lot of research and testing of different solutions, but can't seem to get anything to work for me. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit wait for waiting till you find the element on the page before you click. Here is the sample code for that.

```
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(Driver,<time in MS>);
wait.until(elementToBeClickableAt(By.xpath("<xpath of your element>")));
element.click();
```

Comment: more specifically, I want to wait for it to be visible, I share these switch statements with getText(). So clicking isn't really the root issue, its the face that it is looking for the element and can't find it

Comment: along with the above logic you could alternatively use wait.until(elementIsVisible(By.Id("red-button")));

Comment: element is allowed to click only when the element is visible, So it should work , Alternatively you can try the ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.<your xPath>).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,2000).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id('redButton')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = element(by.id('redButton'));
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(el), 30000).then(function(){
  return;
});
```